# OpenSSL commands to Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl

Is there a way to run the following shell commands only on ruby?

I searched for weeks but I'm afraid it's not very well documented. I've tried a few methods from Ruby 'openssl' but I get different results.

```
%x[openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in key.key -passin pass:passcode -out key.pem]
%x[openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -noout -serial > serial.txt]
%x[openssl dgst -sha256 -out sign.bin -sign key.pem serial.txt]
%x[openssl enc -in sign.bin -a -A -out stamp.txt]
```

Comment: There's a lot of logic to some of those commands wrapped up in the OpenSSL CLI.  There are not single API calls to the OpenSSL API that do many of them.  The last time we faced this prospect we gave up and just shelled out to run the openssl CLI commands.

Comment: Also, ruby's openssl essentially wraps openssl so you need to install the libs anyways. Depending on the distribution and its packaging, the libs can be installed separately from the command line utils, e.g. in ubuntu there is libssl and openssl.